# Problem in understanding the partial differentiation

Tags: summation, partial-derivative

I was reading the book on Neural Network and got stuck up on this equation given below.

\begin{eqnarray}
  z^{l+1}_k = \sum_j w^{l+1}_{kj} a^l_j +b^{l+1}_k = \sum_j w^{l+1}_{kj} \sigma(z^l_j) +b^{l+1}_k.
\tag{43}\end{eqnarray}

here w and b are constant vectors. The equation was then differentiated and below is the result. Where did the summation go?

\begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{\partial z^{l+1}_k}{\partial z^l_j} = w^{l+1}_{kj} \sigma'(z^l_j).
\tag{44}\end{eqnarray}

If you want to see the complete problem then visit http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html eqn 43 and 44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet. It looks like either Einstein summation notation or only one term in the summation is a function of $z_j^l$. I'll say the latter seeing as it says $\sigma(z_j^l)$. $a$ must also be a constant vector.

edit: Einstein summation just means that the sum is implied. You write the variable to be summed over, but not the summation symbol. Very useful at times.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation

Comment: What is einsten summation notation

Comment: But it can cause confusions right?. How to detect them whether they are used are not

Comment: However I understood it thanks. Will you please add these links to the answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation

Answer (score 2):

When taking partial derivative w.r.t. some variable, we treat the other variables as constant. So when the expression on the right is partially differentiated w.r.t. the variable $z_j^l$, all other variables with index other than $j$ are treated constant and so $$\dfrac{\partial \sigma(z_k^l)}{\partial z_j^l}=0$$ when $j\neq k$ and $$\dfrac{\partial \sigma(z_k^l)}{\partial z_j^l}=\sigma'(z_j^l)$$ when $j=k$. I suppose this is the reason the summation vanishes from the right.

Comment: But what makes you think that j is a constant. I didn't understand proprely

Comment: $j$ is just an index for the variables, eg. if there are three variables then $z_1, z_2, z_3$ so $j=1, 2, 3$.

Answer (score 2):

The $z_k$'s are defined over a sum of $z_j$'s.

$$
z^{l+1}_k = \sum_j w^{l+1}_{kj} a^l_j +b^{l+1}_k = \sum_j w^{l+1}_{kj} \sigma(z^l_j) +b^{l+1}_k.
$$

You are differentiating with respect to only one of the $z_j$'s. So, for each $j$, all the other terms in the sum go to zero:

$$
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial z^{l+1}_k}{\partial z^l_j} &=  \frac{\partial }{\partial z^l_j} \left[\sum_j w^{l+1}_{kj} \sigma(z^l_j) +b^{l+1}_k\right]\\
&= \sum_j \frac{\partial }{\partial z^l_j}\left[w^{l+1}_{kj} \sigma(z^l_j) +b^{l+1}_k\right]\\
&= w^{l+1}_{kj} \sigma'(z^l_j).
\tag{44}\end{align}
$$